# Derby Database Access thorugh a local network LAN

Tags: networking, derby

I created a java desktop application with derby client driver using netbeans 8.1.

I used this code to get connected to the database.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LibertySchool;create=true;user=liberty;password=liberty");
conn.setSchema("LIBERTY");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  USUARIOS");
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    Login entrar = new Login();
    entrar.setVisible(true);
}
```

The standalone application is working normal on the pc that it was created on after build the dist file has the app.jar file and everything works normal.

I created this so few client computers can access the same application to update data. I have started the derby network on client machine, I have also change the connection from localhost to use the app database location ip server.

But my app does not work on clients on the same network only on the computer where it was built. Other applications that do not use databases works well over the network, it seems that derby database folder has to be moved also to the client machine.

I need to know how to set the client machine properly so users can access the app with the database.

Can someone please give some hints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a client-server connection with the client on a different machine than the server, you'll have to do several things:

1. Change `localhost` to a valid externally visible address for the server machine. You can use an IP address, or a host name, e.g., `192.168.1.104:1527` or `Carlos-Mac-Pro.att.net:1527`, but you're going to need to figure out the right network address to use. `localhost:1527` will only work when the client and server are on the same machine.
2. Ensure that your network allows connections between the client machines and the server machine. Nowadays, most machines will, by default, prevent most inbound network connections from other machines, as a security measure, so you'll need to configure the server machine's firewall, as well as any network devices that are being used in your local network between the client machines and the server machine, to allow TCP/IP connections on port 1527.

I don't think you want to move the derby database folder to the client machines. That would be a completely different architecture for your application (embedded vs client-server). Here's some good background material about the differences between the two configurations: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have use the client IP address and the app did run, but only like I mentioned before. I will configure server firewall I have not done that, I have the host name as well but no luck. thanks